# Assign Two values in shell script array

Tags: shell

I wonder , if we can save two values , for example , name and number , in the same array member , for example , i have write the following code to do this :

```
`array[$count]={$x , 1}`
```

where `$x` containe a string , but when i want to print the value that `array[$count]` have :

```
`echo "$count - $x1 - ${array[$count]} \n"`
```

it's give just the first value which is `$x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash does not have multidimensional arrays, but you can fake it using associative arrays:

```
$ declare -A array
$ count=5
$ array[$count,name]="foobar"
$ array[$count,value]=1
$ for idx in "${!array[@]}"; do printf "%s\t%s\n" "$idx" "${array[$idx]}"; done
5,value 1
5,name  foobar
```

This requires bash version 4

Comment: does associative array is similar to hash in perl ?
and another question , can i change 'value' , since it should not be a fixed value ?

Comment: Yes, associative array is like a hash. But it can only store strings as values. You don't want to change the word "value" in the array index, you want to change the actual value (where I have "1").

Comment: okay "value" , what will be , in another word , what will be assign ?

Comment: whatever is on the right-hand side of `=` will be assigned to the variable named on the left-hand side

Comment: but what will happen if we assign a value with key that already exist ?

Comment: Then you lose the old value. That is exactly the same as `x=1; x=2`

Comment: shells have very rudimentary data structures. If you need something more flexible, use a different language (perl, etc)

Comment: im actually doing an assignment , and it have to be in shell scripting !!

Comment: is there a way to ckeck if this key is exist in the array ?

Comment: `if [[ -n ${array[$key]} ]]` will check to see if that value at that key is non-empty.